# Beyond Compare resync lines

Tags: windows, beyondcompare

I'm using Beyond Compare 4 Trial Mode to compare to .csv files.  Many years ago I recall there was a command to resync the file comparison.  One of my csv files has more lines to the other and I need to be able to manually pick match this line to that line in few places.  I'm pretty sure this used to be available.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beyond Compare's **Table Compare** (default view for CSV and XLSX files) doesn't support manual alignment of rows. Rows are automatically aligned based on key columns.

The default settings make column 1 a key column. To change the column type, right click on a column header and select **Standard Column** or **Key Column**.

To change the row sorting behavior in the **Table Compare**, click the **Rules** toolbar button (referee icon). In the **Alignment** tab, select **Sorted alignment**, **Unaligned**, etc.

Beyond Compare's **Text Compare** does support manual alignment of lines. To open files in the **Text Compare** when they're already open in the **Table Compare**, select **Session > Compare Files Using > Text Compare**. In the **Text Compare**, right click on a line on the left and select **Align With**, then left click on a line on the right.